# Kafka consumer is not reading from only one partition out of 4

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was using Kafka 0.9 and recently migrated to Kafka 1.0, but the client I am using is still 0.9. Irrespective of this I was facing a problem where our consumers sometimes intermittently stop consuming from one or two of the partitions.

I have 5 consumers reading from 24 partitions, these are consumer JVM threads created from an application deployed in the single server. Frequently one of the consumer (thread) will stop reading from one of the partitions it would be consuming from.

Eg: One consumer thread would be reading from partition 1,2,3,and 4. It will stop reading from partition 1 and end up in building the lag. I have to restart the consumer to start picking those messages from that particular partition.

I want to understand the issue here.

My consumer configuration

```
session.timeout.ms=150000
request.timeout.ms=300000
max.partition.fetch.bytes=153600
```

Comment: Do you see any re-balancing happening for the corresponding consumer-group? You can refer to the `server.log` for that.

Comment: No, I am not seeing it. It used to happen before as I was polling more data and session was timing out before I process those messages and try to commit. I resolved it by reducing the fetch bytes.